# Email Problem - Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, email

Windows Server 2008 , Server Manager-> File Services->Share and Storage Management->File Server Resource Manager > Right click -> Configure options-> Email Notifications tab

I have already configured  what I need but when I write for example  smpt.google.com 
in the log it writes   `UNABLE TO CONNECT TO THE REMOTE SERVER`

I have been through this article  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947057

Please help me..

maybe this is a firewall problem?

Comment: just a sneaking suspicion, but have you checked for typos ;)

Comment: Upvoted and Fav'd. Troubleshooting 101.

Answer (score 6):

Because smPT.google.com doesnt exist. You should try smTP.google.com.

Comment: our just smtp.google.com...

Answer (score 1):

**I think the most likely causes for this problem would be:**

- You have not configured SMTP Authentication. Google does not allow anonymous SMTP; you must log in with your Google user / password first.
- You don't connect over SSL. As far as I know, Google requires SMTP over SSL.

It could be a firewall issue; but my bet is on one of the above. But try going to the command line, and telnet to smtp.google.com on port 25 (SMTP). Does it connect (does the remote server respond with any kind of ASCII text commands), or does it just time out... If it just times out, then a firewall is blocking the traffic, or the host name or port is wrong.

I think [this link should be very helpful](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775) for you, regarding how to connect to Googles SMTP over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is how to setup in WS2k8 authentication of SMTP server. Looks like there is no option to setup authorized SMTP connection. So you can setup only anonymous unsecure SMTP server.

File Server Resource Manager Options:

[image: File Server Resource Manager Options]